# Hyperlink in a long text Area

Tags: custom-field, fields, hyperlink, long-text-area

I have a long text area field on an object.
There is a link present for each record on that field which works fine at the record level but does work on reports.
I want to make the link **clickable in the reports** . Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this :

Create a formula in Excel to generate hyperlinks.

When you build your report, include the Record ID for the Object you'd like to hyperlink to. When you export the report, insert a new column and enter a formula to generate a hyperlink to the record in your organization.

Example Scenario: The Case Record ID is in column A of your report export.

1. Insert a new column to the right of Column A.
2. In cell B2, enter =HYPERLINK("https://instance.salesforce.com/"&A2)

Note: Replace instance in the URL above with the instance of your Salesforce Org. For example: NA7 or EU13.

3. Copy this formula down to all cells and you will now have a hyperlink from your export file back to each Case record.